# Storing encrypted password in database but decrypt it on the client side

Tags: encryption, javascript, node.js

Language used is Javascript.

For context, I am making a password manager where users can store different accounts of service and their passwords. The idea was to store multiple encrypted passwords in the database and decrypt them on the client side to display them to the users without any input from the user.

What is the ideal way to go around this?

I am aware this method is not recommended as the encryption key could be stolen from the client side. Regardless, I would like to hear any thoughts on this.

Comment: I've edited your question and changed "hashed/encrypted passwords" to only encrypted since hashed cannot be decrypted.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Okay, thanks buddy

Comment: Just checking, is this a serious product you're making, or a toy/academic thing? Because there's a substantial number of zero-trust end-to-end encrypted online password managers already, and - even if you have some feature you want to create that the existing ones are missing - if you have to ask a question like this, you shouldn't be trying to create a new one.

Comment: Check out the [web crypto api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).  This API contains a complete set of cryptographic primitives that you can access using client-side javascript.

Comment: @CBHacking, it's an academic thing. Just a school project I'm working on.

Comment: @mti2935 I have checked it out, but it seems like it requires input from the client side. Preferably I would like for the client to have no input other than to login into the main account in the first place.

Comment: @cannons, See protonmail.com/blog/encrypted_email_authentication for an interesting read on how protonmail uses SRP to derive two keys from a single password entered by the user when the user logs in - one key that is used to authenticate with the server, and another key that is used for client-side cryptography..

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Are users expected to log into a remote database [service], or is it all local to the client? In the latter case, what even is the purpose of the encryption, since the key would need to be stored alongside the encrypted data and presumably anybody who could steal either one would get both? If it's a client-server infrastructure, how do users authenticate to the server? If you don't have a full threat model, do you at least have a list of components and interactions and/or a data flow diagram?

Comment: unless they are prompted for a master password each time, you'd be vulnerable.  You can be less vulnerable if you use the machine's serial number as part of the key.  (the data can still be stolen, but the malicious actor would have to run something to get the serial number/key...) You could also use something like DPAPI which uses a similar approach and is tied to a user on the machine.  Or have it phone home for the key each time... tie that to a user account on the server where only hash or token is stored client-side.  (SSL server of course)  No one would know the password but the user.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to "enjoy both worlds" in the following sense:
*Assuming* that the server doesn't need to know the actual contents of the passwords you can employ the following scheme:

1. The client generates a client key for the password
2. The client encrypts the password via said key
3. The client uploads the *client encrypted* password to the server
4. The server, before storing this ciphertext in the DB, also generates a key and
5. The server encrypts the password with this independent, *server generated* key
6. The server stores the password in the DB which is *doubly encrypted* (first via client key, then via server key)
7. Needless to say, before the server sends a password to the user, it will need to remove its own layer of encryption (=decrypt) via using the same key it generated.

Now, perhaps the most important point which is relevant to the security of this entire setup, is that the client key/s should be protected via a *passphrase* that the client must enter whenever he wants to access a password. Ideally, the program should be written so that the client key/s are always stored encrypted and get decrypted only in *volatile* memory after the appropriate passphrase has been entered. You can then derive a "main client key" from this passphrase...

This is only a rough sketch of how to tackle this, and a lot more can be done to improve this probably. For example if you're talking about Windows in particular, you can employ DPAPI and in some scenarios it can replace the passphrase...

*Important comment*: whenever I wrote "generate a key" it also means that you need to store this key somewhere, since those are long term keys (used for encryption of what is, eventually, persistent data in the form of a password, as opposed to transient keys which are employed for example, for communication...)

Comment: BTW if you need to authenticate to a server anyway, you can store the client key there as well (and the server can protect it via a server generated key). It's a rule of thumb in client-server architectures that a server is less vulnerable than the client (which is usually true, as you have more control over the servers), so it follows that you should prefer using that server to store sensitive data, over storing it on the client side. Then essentially the authentication step (which is for example, password based) is your "bridge" to the sensitive data that's on the server.

Comment: The down side of that is the privacy aspect: if the server knows your client key, it can decrypt your local password data. So consider mixing both secret materials that are on the server and on the client, to derive the final client key. ("Enjoying both worlds" once more :))